# Is there a faster way to get a definite numerical value for the following permutation/ combinaions question?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> The ratio of boys to girls at birth in Singapore is 1.09:1 Then the
> proportion of Singaporean families with exactly 6 children who will
> have at least 3 boys is
>
> A. 0:696
>
> B. 0:315
>
> C. 0:521
>
> D. 0:455

While i know the answer should be $$\binom{6}{3}\frac{1.09}{2.09}^{3}\frac{1}{2.09}^{3}+\binom{6}{4}\frac{1.09}{2.09}^{4}\frac{1}{2.09}^{2}$$......

Is there any way in which i can come to the 0.696 value without a calculator fast enough?

We are not allowed calculators in exams and the sample paper contains this question.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a strict prove at all and in general situation with high orders can work absolutely wrong, but I think you can reason in this way:

$\binom 63 = 20$

$\binom 64 = 15$

$\binom 65 = 6$

$\binom 66 = 1$

So your final probability expression could be written like this:

$(\frac{1.09^3}{2.09^6})*(20+15*1.09+6*1.09^2+1*1.09^3)=(\frac{1.09^3}{2.09^3})*(\frac{20+15*1.09+6*1.09^2+1*1.09^3}{2.09^3})$

The first fraction $(\frac{1.09^3}{2.09^3})$ i think could be approximately rewritten as $(\frac{1.09^3}{2.09^3})\approx(\frac{1}{2})^3=0.125$

The second $(\frac{20+15*1.09+6*1.09^2+1*1.09^3}{2.09^3})\approx(\frac{42}{8})=5.25$

Thus your result will be $\approx0.125*5.25=0.65625$ which is pretty close to the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You need two more terms in your sum, for five and six boys.  I don't know a faster way to compute the actual value, but it is easy to see that among the choices given the answer must be A.  The chance has to be greater than $0.5$, which eliminates B and D.  If there were the same number of boys and girls, the chance of having at least three boys in six would be higher than $0.521$ because we succeed with a $3-3$ tie.  Having more boys than girls only raises the ratio.  $0.521$ is too small to be believable.

To be exact, assuming equal numbers of boys and girls, the chance of at least three boys is $\frac 12+\frac 12{6 \choose 3}2^{-6}=\frac 12 + \frac {20}{128}=\frac {21}{32}\approx 0.656$  Having more boys than girls only raises this.